# How to get unique values to compare two columns of the same table?

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, django-queryset

Currently, I am working on a Django project using SQLite in which I create a message chatbox and I want to fetch the most recent message of logged in user whether it's sent or received.

```
id   receiver_id      sender_id    message_content   created_at
1    1                 2            some text         2020-08-11 13:29:47.342944
3    3                 2            some text         2020-08-11 13:44:55.499638
4    2                 1            some text         2020-08-11 14:20:55.499638
5    1                 2            some text         2020-08-12 05:06:05.497500
6    2                 5            some text         2020-08-12 10:39:31.234082
7    4                 1            some text         2020-08-14 13:25:19.357876
```

After using below SQL query.

```
SELECT max(created_at), * 
FROM hireo_messages 
WHERE receiver_id=2 or sender_id=2 
GROUP BY receiver_id, sender_id 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I got the following result.

```
id      receiver_id   sender_id     message_content   created_at
6       2             5             some text         2020-08-12 10:39:31.234082
5       1             2             some text         2020-08-12 05:06:05.497500
4       2             1             some text         2020-08-11 14:20:55.499638
3       3             2             some text         2020-08-11 13:44:55.499638
```

And as you can see id 5, 4 both chat with each other. So I want to fetch all records except id 4 because the most recent chat between 2 users is in id 5. It same concept as used in the Facebook messenger dashboard.
please guide me whether it solve with a query or use any other way. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If the message `id` is auto incremented or some equivalent, you shouldn't have to worry about `order` ing the data, the `id` by definition gives you the order. `SELECT max(id), * FROM hireo_messages WHERE receiver_id=2 or sender_id=2 GROUP BY receiver_id, sender_id;` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function `MAX()`:

```
select id, receiver_id, sender_id, message_content, created_at 
from (
  select *,
    max(created_at) over (partition by min(receiver_id, sender_id), max(receiver_id, sender_id)) last_date
  from hireo_messages
  where 2 in (receiver_id, sender_id) 
)
where created_at = last_date
order by id desc
```

If your version of SQLite does not support window functions you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select h.* from hireo_messages h
where 2 in (receiver_id, sender_id)
and not exists (
  select 1 from hireo_messages
  where min(receiver_id, sender_id) = min(h.receiver_id, h.sender_id)
    and max(receiver_id, sender_id) = max(h.receiver_id, h.sender_id)
  and created_at > h.created_at
)  
order by h.id desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9ca0f47a3da6a196066afc400a45c5ee).
Results:

```
| id  | receiver_id | sender_id | message_content | created_at                 |
| --- | ----------- | --------- | --------------- | -------------------------- |
| 6   | 2           | 5         | some text       | 2020-08-12 10:39:31.234082 |
| 5   | 1           | 2         | some text       | 2020-08-12 05:06:05.497500 |
| 3   | 3           | 2         | some text       | 2020-08-11 13:44:55.499638 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT LEAST(receiver_id, sender_id), GREATEST(receiver_id, sender_id), MAX(created_at)
FROM hireo_messages
WHERE 2 IN (receiver_id, sender_id)
GROUP BY LEAST(receiver_id, sender_id), GREATEST(receiver_id, sender_id)
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC;
```

If you want the complete row, use window functions:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (SELECT m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(receiver_id, sender_id), GREATEST(receiver_id, sender_id) ORDER BY created_at DESC) as seqnum
      FROM hireo_messages m
      WHERE 2 IN (receiver_id, sender_id)
     ) m
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC;
```

Comment: @UmairKhan . . . So much for being the first one to answer.